# Stepper motor math with constant acceleration

Tags: embedded, stepper

I need to write a program to control a stepper motor using an atmega328P and an A4988 chip.
I've been looking for suitable libaries but so far I haven't been to find a suitable one.

I need a turntable to turn to pre-taught in absolute positions. I thought that the motor in question had 20000 steps per revolution with 1/16th microstepping. When the position counter reaches 20000 it must be set back to 0 and vice versa. So traveling from 19999 to 1 can be done in both directions.

I would like the stepper motor to accelerate and decelerate linear. This is the one thing I do not exactly know how to do this.

I want to use the micros() timer function of the arduino IDE to time the pulses on the step pin.

I can calculate how much pulses I have to travel, and I can increment/decrement speed with a fixed interval but I am having difficulties with calculating when to start decelerating.

If I adjust the speed, after every time I take a step, the acceleration is not linear. I tried to calculate the braking distance with: pulses = V*V / 2. Which I derived from basic movement and travel formula. S(t) = S0 + V0 * t - 0.5*A*t^2. I take 1 for A and 1 for T. Every time I inc/dec the speed with 1. So I get S(1) = V^2 - 0.5 * V^2 = 0. * V^2 or V^2 / 2.

Incrementing speed is not synchronized with the pulses and I am not sure how to fix this.

I could use some pointers.

Background:
The stepper will be controlling a model railway turntable. The turntable will be correctly connected to the axle of the motor.
The controller will have 4 buttons.

- manual/automatic button.
- CW
- CCW
- store position

In automatic mode the motor can shift from one taught in position to another position by pressing CW and CCW. It must also be possible to accept a new position when the turntable is still turning.

In manual mode I can use the same CW and CCW buttons to cruise the turntable manually. When I hold a button the motor needs to accelerate to pre-set maximum speed, when I release the button the motor need to decelerator to 0.

With the store button I can save the current position in one of the 20 reserved slots.

The first time that the controller is powered up, it will take the motor's current physical position as a virtual zero point. Every time when the turntable stops, it's current position will be stored in EEPROM. May it be obvious that the turntable won't be move from external force when the controller is turned off.

Edit for the comment + answer

I have already made a simple state machine.
[image]

I am not using any library to control the stepper, I currently use the micros() timer to set steps.

All the code between the macros REPEAT_MS and END_REPEAT runs with the given interval in us

```
void setSteps()
{
    uint8_t speedVar = 255 - speed ;
    REPEAT_US( speedVar ) ;
    
    if( enabled ) 
    {
        if( !digitalRead( dirPin ) )
        {
            if( ++position == maxPos+1 ) position = 1 ; // verify this code if positions work well
            digitalWrite( stepPin, HIGH ) ;                
            digitalWrite( stepPin,  LOW ) ;                // slow enough for mininum pulse duration
        }
        else
        {
            //if( --position == 0 ) position = maxPos ; // currently run 1 direction
        }
    }
    Serial.print("position: ");
    Serial.println( position ) ;

    else 
    {
        digitalWrite( stepPin, state ) ;// may become port manipulated
        return ;
    }
    END_REPEAT
}
```

To control speed:

```
void manageSpeed()
{ 
    REPEAT_MS( ACCELERATION_FACTOR ) ;          // separate fixed timing for constant acceleration and deceleration
    
    static uint8_t speedPrev = 255 ;
    
    if( speedSetpoint > speed ) speed ++ ;
    if( speedSetpoint < speed ) speed -- ;
    if( speed == 0 ) enabled = false ;          // if speed reaches 0, stop sending pulses
    
    if( speedPrev != speed ) {
        speedPrev  = speed ;
        Serial.print("SPEED :") ;
        Serial.println( speed ) ;
    }
    END_REPEAT
}
```

And the less important used macros (they work fine, are well tested)

```
#define REPEAT_MS(x)    { \
                            static uint32_t previousTime ;\
                                   uint32_t currentTime = millis() ;\
                            if( currentTime  - previousTime >= x ) {\
                                previousTime = currentTime ;
                                // code to be repeated goes between these 2 macros
                                
#define REPEAT_US(x)    { \
                            static uint32_t previousTime ;\
                                   uint32_t currentTime = micros() ;\
                            if( currentTime  - previousTime >= x ) {\
                                previousTime = currentTime ;
                                // code to be repeated goes between these 2 macros
#define END_REPEAT          } \
                        }
```

I will take a close look and try to implement the tapezoidal controller and try to implement the suggested formulas.

2nd EDIT:
I have a somewhat working code at the moment, but there is this one thing I cannot comprehend.

Currently I am adjust the speed every 100ms with 1. 1 is the acceleration factor. The total acceleration time is 3500ms as 35 is my max speed.

This is the output during acceleration. I had to fine tweak the step interval a bit.
SPEED :34
Last Time: 100  total time: 3400
distanceToGo: 6853
total position: 1147

```
SPEED :35
Last Time: 100  total time: 3500
distanceToGo: 6784
total position: 1216

cruising
```

This 1216 should be 1225. With P(t) = 0.5 * 1 * 35^2 = 1225 pulses. However it is sorta close enough.

Than with decelerating:

```
braking


SPEED :34
Last Time: 27  total time: 11400
distanceToGo: 1207
total position: 6793

SPEED :33
Last Time: 100  total time: 11500
distanceToGo: 1137
total position: 6863

...

SPEED :0
Last Time: 100  total time: 14800
distanceToGo: -8
total position: 8008
Last Time: 1  total time: 14801
distanceToGo: -8
total position: 8008
```

I have an overshoot of 8 which is acceptable. However what I do not get is the following. The calculation of the interval of the step time now is

```
 REPEAT_US( 47950 / speed ) ;
```

The 47950 is besides imperfect, also in-calculable. I found it with trial and error and cannot reason why it is what it is.

How does the position controller method approximately work?

Comment: There is probably too much words and too little code in this question.  Including the code yo have will allow someone to provide an answer you can use directly.  For example you say you have not found a suitable stepper library, but you are obviously using something?  What is wrong with https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Stepper for example or do you mean a higher level motion control library?

Comment: You should do it as a position controller (easy with a stepper) and change position over time.  By implementing it as a speed controller you end up with that "fineTunePos" blob which you should not need.

Comment: Is it a good idea to implement a PID control system for such a position controller?

Comment: Not for  a stepper motor.  You need closed-loop feedback for that.  Stepper motor control is normally open-loop.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368757/why-arent-stepper-motors-used-in-closed-loop-systems-and-pid-control/368822

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you require as I understand it is a position controller with defined acceleration and deceleration from and to the target position.  The simplest form of motion control for this is a "tapezoidal" controller - that is one with linear acceleration, a constant maximum, and linear deceleration; forming a trapezium if you plot speed over time.  When the position change is small, the maximum speed may not be met, in which case the motion is triangular.

A suitable class for implementing this might have:

- parameters defining the trapezoid (acceleration, max velocity, deceleration),
- a parameter for the position range (0 to 20000 in your case), so that when a specific position position set-point is set, the controller can set the direction for the shortest motion,
- A set-point function for defining the target position,
- An update function that determines the position error (the difference between current position and required position and issues the required number of steps to zero the error). This function need only be called frequently enough to ensure smooth motion, ideally so it issues not more than one step at a time

The units for such a class might be in terms of steps (steps/s, steps/s<sup>2</sup>) or degrees, or whatever.  I suggest using steps - it will give the finest control and lowest CPU load, and it is system independent - for example if you were driving a linear actuator or a vehicle or have additional gearing, degrees don't make much sense and you'd be doing additional calculations to translate the into the real-world system domain in any case.

The tricky part perhaps is determining when to stop accelerating and when to start decelerating.  In this application, I suggest you keep it simple and do not allow the set-point/target position to be changed before a motion is completed.  That makes calculation simpler because the velocity will always be zero when you plan the trapezoid.  Equally there is no need in this application to support dynamic changes of acceleration to velocity.

So the fundamental equation we need is:

*p(t) = v<sub>0</sub>t + 0.5at<sup>2</sup>*

Such that the position at any particular time *t* - i.e. *p(t)* - is the initial velocity plus half acceleration squared.

For the trapezoidal phases (1), (2), (3):

```
       ^      _________________
       |    /|                |\
 Vel   |   / |                | \
       |  /  |                |  \
       | /(1)|      (2)       |(3)\
       ------------------------------>
                 time
```

The equations are:

- (1) *p(t) = 0.5a<sub>accel</sub> . t<sup>2</sup>*
- (2) *p(t) = v<sub>max</sub> . t*
- (3) *p(t) = v<sub>max</sub> . t - 0.5a<sub>decel</sub> . t<sup>2</sup>*

Noting that at each phase *t* is reset, and *p(t)* is relative to the position at the start of the phase (incremental).

However for short distances, the motion is triangular, and v<sup>max</sup> will not be reached. Then you have to start decelerating when the stopping distance less-than-or-equal to the remaining distance.

An additional equation is useful here:

- (4) *v = at*

You can use this at each update during phase (1) (*v = at*), and phase (2) (*v = v<sub>max</sub>) to determine the "stopping distance" (*v<sup>2</sup> / 2a*) to determine the start of phase (3).

I suggest therefore that the update function be implemented as a state machine for each phase.

The implementation below has been tested numerically in a test harness running on a PC.  It assumes the use of the standard [Arduino Library `Stepper` class](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/stepper) to perform the actual stepping, and the class takes a reference to a `Stepper` object so you can control multiple motors.  I have not (yet) tested it on real hardware.  I stubbed the `millis()` function and `Stepper` class to run it on a PC.

```c++
class cTrapezoidStepper
{
    public:

        cTrapezoidStepper( Stepper& stepper, int32_t accel, int32_t vmax, int32_t decel, int32_t range ) :
            m_stepper( stepper ),
            m_accel( accel ),
            m_vmax( vmax ),
            m_vpeak( 0 ),
            m_decel( decel ),
            m_range( range ),
            m_start_time( 0 ),
            m_current_pos( 0 ),
            m_target_delta( 0 ),
            m_direction( 0 ),
            m_distance_moved( 0 ),
            m_trap_phase( STOP )
        {

        }

        bool isMoving()
        {
            return m_trap_phase != 0 ;
        }

        int32_t setTargetPos( int32_t target )
        {
            if( m_trap_phase == STOP &&
                target != m_current_pos )
            {
                // Determine number of steps and direction to target
                m_target_delta = target % m_range - m_current_pos ;
                if( abs( m_target_delta ) > m_range / 2 )
                {
                    m_target_delta -= m_range ;
                }

                m_direction = 1 ;
                if( m_target_delta < 0 )
                {
                    m_target_delta = -m_target_delta ;
                    m_direction = -1 ;
                }

                // Init motion
                m_start_time = tick() ;
                m_distance_moved = 0  ;
                m_trap_phase = ACCEL ;
            }

            return m_target_delta ;
        }

        int32_t update()
        {
            int32_t t = tick() - m_start_time ;
            int32_t distance_to_move = m_distance_moved ;
            int32_t distance_to_target = m_target_delta - m_distance_moved ; 
            int32_t current_velocity = 0 ;
            int32_t stopping_distance = 0 ;

            switch( m_trap_phase )
            {
                case ACCEL :
                {
                    current_velocity = (m_accel * t) / ONE_SECOND ;
                    stopping_distance = (current_velocity * current_velocity) / (2 * m_decel) ;

                    m_vpeak = current_velocity ;
                    if( distance_to_target <= stopping_distance )
                    {
                        // Reset for next phase
                        m_start_time = tick() ;
                        m_target_delta = distance_to_target ; 
                        m_distance_moved = 0 ;
                        distance_to_move = 0 ;

                        m_trap_phase = DECEL ;
                    }
                    else if( current_velocity >= m_vmax )
                    {
                        // Reset for next phase
                        m_start_time = tick() ;
                        m_target_delta = distance_to_target ; 
                        m_distance_moved = 0 ;
                        distance_to_move = 0 ;

                        m_trap_phase = CONSTANT ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        distance_to_move = m_accel * (t * t) / (2 * ONE_SECOND * ONE_SECOND) ;
                    }
                }
                break ;

                case CONSTANT :
                {
                    m_vpeak = m_vmax ;
                    current_velocity = m_vmax ;
                    stopping_distance = (current_velocity * current_velocity) / (2 * m_decel) ;

                    if( distance_to_target <= stopping_distance )
                    {
                        // Reset for next phase
                        m_start_time = tick() ;
                        m_target_delta = distance_to_target ; 
                        m_distance_moved = 0 ;
                        distance_to_move = 0 ;

                        m_trap_phase = DECEL ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        distance_to_move = (t * m_vmax) / ONE_SECOND ;
                    }
                }
                break ;

                case DECEL :
                {
                    current_velocity = m_vpeak - (m_decel * t) / ONE_SECOND ;

                    if( distance_to_target <= 0 )
                    {
                        m_trap_phase = STOP ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        distance_to_move = (m_vpeak * t) / ONE_SECOND - 
                                           (m_decel * (t * t) / (2 * ONE_SECOND * ONE_SECOND)) ;
                    }
                }
                break ;

                default :
                {
                    distance_to_move = m_distance_moved ;
                }
                break ;
            }


            // Do steps
            int32_t steps = (distance_to_move - m_distance_moved) * m_direction ;
            m_stepper.step( steps ) ;

            // Update position
            m_distance_moved = distance_to_move ;
            m_current_pos += steps ;
            m_current_pos %= m_range ;

            return m_current_pos ;
        }

    private :
        static const int32_t ONE_SECOND = 100 ;

        Stepper& m_stepper ;
        int32_t m_accel ;
        int32_t m_vmax ;
        int32_t m_vpeak ;
        int32_t m_decel ; 
        int32_t m_range ;
        unsigned long m_start_time ;
        int32_t m_current_pos ;
        int32_t m_target_delta ;
        int32_t m_direction ;
        int32_t m_distance_moved ;
        enum
        {
            STOP,
            ACCEL,
            CONSTANT,
            DECEL
        } m_trap_phase ;

        int32_t tick(){ return millis() / (1000 / ONE_SECOND) ; }

};
```

The test (Windows not Arduino code, and not how you might use it in a Sketch `loop()`) looked like this:

```c++
int main()
{
    Stepper dummy ;
    cTrapezoidStepper turntable( dummy, 100, 600, 150, 20000 ) ;
    turntable.setTargetPos( 5000  ) ;
    while( turntable.isMoving() )
    {
        turntable.update() ;
    }
    Sleep(5000) ;
    turntable.setTargetPos( 2500 ) ;
    while( turntable.isMoving() )
    {
        turntable.update() ;
    }
    Sleep(5000) ;

    turntable.setTargetPos( 6000 ) ;
    while( turntable.isMoving() )
    {
        turntable.update() ;
    }
    Sleep(5000) ;
    turntable.setTargetPos( 0 ) ;
    while( turntable.isMoving() )
    {
        turntable.update() ;
    }
}
```

So

```c++
cTrapezoidStepper turntable( dummy, 100, 600, 150, 20000 ) ;
```

Instantiates a controller with:

- Acceleration 100 steps/s<sup>2</sup>
- Maximum speed 600 steps/s
- Acceleration 150 steps/s<sup>2</sup>
- Step range 0 to 19999 steps.

When you set the position, it will take the shortest direction to teh target.

The test moves to position 5000, 2500, 6000 then 0 in turn, with a delat between each move.  The potion profile looks like:

[image]
Note that velocity during the delay is not shown flat - that is an artefact of the test output and the fact that the precision deceleration calculation is such that it is not exactly zero when the target position is reached (though it does stop as seen from the position profile.  I am sure that can be fixed, but I am also sure that it is probably negligible in this application.  It stops at around 38 steps/second or about 0.1 RPM.

Note also the second move is triangular as it is too short a distance to reach the maximum velocity.

To perform a similar test in a Sketch you might have a `loop()` like:

```c++
void loop()
{
    int32_t positions[] = { 19000, 4000, 2500, 6000, 0 } ;
    static int test = -1 ;
    
    if( !turntable.isMoving() )
    {
        test = (test + 1) % (sizeof(positions) / sizeof(*positions)) ;
        turntable.setTargetPos( positions[test] ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        turntable.update() ;
    }
}
```

Note the member function `cTrapezoidStepper::tick()` which I have implemented to reduce the timing resolution to 100ms intervals.  This should be fine for smooth control, but was necessary to prevent arithmetic overflow (which you may still encounter if you use very low accelerations - that part could be improved if you wanted to make it more general purpose).

Comment: I understand these functions, (3) I tried to use with a decel facor of '1' and for 't' I filled in 'V'. I figured that If I am turning at 255 P/s that I need 255s to reach a speed of 0. And I keep the decel factor at '1' I can use the update interval time to control the actual acceleration. But I must have done it wrong.

Comment: I have extensively updated the answer - the equations at the time you used them may not have been correct, but equally there are many gotchas with fixed point math scaling and arithmetic overflow.

Comment: Thank you for al your effort. It is greatly appreciated. I will try to implement most of it. Only setTargetPos will be seeing some modifications for me. I am going to be turning with the longest distance in the opposite direction deliberately. But I can figure that out.